# Passing JSON response To tinymce template config init value

Tags: javascript, json, tinymce

Hello guys i was try to following documentation of tinymce text editor about template plugins, in official tinymce website
[Documetation Template Plugins Tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/template/)
but cant working with json response im foollowing init from tiny mce like this.

**Ajax Setup**

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('admin_surat/json_get_template') ?>",
    cache: false,
});

$("#surat_template_id").change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                id: value
            },
            success: function(respond) {
                var obj = respond.response.text;
            }
        })
    }
});
```

**Ajax Response**

```
{
  "title": "Surat Undangan",
  "description": "Surat Undangan",
  "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/ci-eoffice\/upload\/template-surat\/surat_undangan.html"
}
```

**TinyMCE Init on HTML FILE**

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "template",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "template",
  templates: [obj]
});
```

My question Is How To passing json response into Template config on TinyMCE init ? thannks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing a valid array to `templates`, in your ajax success:

```
var obj = respond.response.text;
var objArray = [];
objArray.push(obj);
```

And on tinymce.init:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "template",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "template",
  templates: objArray
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alot, Its working with var obj = JSON.parse(respond);
                      objArray.push(obj);